# Symfony EasyAdmin CRUD > do something after crud save / update

Tags: symfony, crud, easyadmin

i am new in symfony and struggling to find a solution to a rather simple problem. I am using EasyAdmin crud and all default functionality is great and works, but problem is i need a custom code executed when create new / update action happens.

Basically i need to send an email on SAVE (regardless of it is saving a new item or updating existing item), i need a function where i have access to the entity instance that is being saved.

e.g. if i save an user, i need access to that user, so that i can do things like:
send an email which will contain user info from saved instance (username, email)..

any simple example for this?
thank you!

i tried adding function createEntity() but it replaces form rather than being used as an additional function to execute on save.

forgot to mention that i use symfony 6 and easyadmin 4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice way for you to do this is the following:

1. Create the `mailer` object as a property for the Crud Controller.
2. Create a `__construct` and inject the dependency in there.
3. Override the `persistEntity()` method, call the parent and then execute your custom code.

Quick example:

```
class UserCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    protected $mailer;

    //...
    public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
         $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function persistEntity(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityInstance): void
    {
        parent::persistEntity($entityManager, $entityInstance);
        /** 
        // custom code goes here.
        $message = ''; // put together a message...
        $this->mailer->sendEmail($message); 
        **/
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @Aries ! :) i found a solution back then, i used getSubscribedEvents() to accomplish this. But hopefully your answer will help others with same issue :)